# How should I call object methods from a static method in a ruby class?

Tags: ruby

From an academic / "for interests sake" (best practice) perspective:

In a Ruby class, I want to provide a static method that calls instance methods of the class. Is this considered an acceptable way of doing it, or is there is a "better" way?

```
class MyUtil
    def apiClient
      @apiClient ||= begin
         apiClient = Vendor::API::Client.new("mykey")
      end
    end

    def self.setUpSomething(param1, param2, param3=nil)
      util = self.new() # <-- is this ok?
      util.apiClient.call("foo", param2)
      # some logic and more util.apiClient.calls() re-use client.
    end
end
```

And then I can use this lib easily:

```
MyUtil.setUpSomething("yes","blue")
```

vs

```
MyUtil.new().setupUpSomething()
# or
util = MyUtil.new()
util.setUpSomething()
```

The environment is sys admin scripts that get executed in a controlled manner, 1 call at a time (i.e. not a webapp type of environment that could be subjected to high load).

Comment: any good reason for not making `setUpSomething` as instance method? or `apiClient` as class?

Comment: The better ways have traditionally been the Singleton or Builder patterns, or a factory method.

Comment: @nitind : +1 for singleton pattern. This could work fine here.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Just for statically calling in scripts / ease of use. Instead of instantiating and then calling, i can just call. So not sure if that qualifies as a "good reason" - which is 1 approach I considered, but wanted to know that if I did want to just access a static method from a script, how would i call instance methods from there.  Looking into singleton / builder patterns and factory methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would probably do something like:

```
class MyUtil
  API_KEY = "mykey"

  def apiClient
    @apiClient 
  end

  def initialize
    @apiClient = Vendor::API::Client.new(API_KEY)
    yield self if block_given?
  end

  class << self

    def setUpSomthing(arg1,arg2,arg3=nil)
        self.new do |util|
            #setup logic goes here
        end     
    end

    def api_call(arg1,arg2,arg3)
        util = setUpSomthing(arg1,arg2,arg3)
        util.apiClient.call("foo", param2)
        #do other stuff
    end

  end

end
```

The difference is subtle but in this version `setUpSomthing` guarantees a  return of the instance of the class and it's more obvious what you're doing.

Here `setUpSomthing` is responsible for setting up the object and then returning it so it can be used for things, this way you have a clear separation of creating the object and setting the object up.

Comment: `self` in `self.new` is redundant.

Comment: Depends, I like being explicit is all, but you are right in that it's not really needed beyond that.

Comment: There is no difference between `new` and `setUpSomething` methods but for an unknown reason, you call one with and the other without the explicit receiver. This is not an explicitness, this is a code smell.

Comment: There is a difference, `initialize` would be used to set up defaults, I.E to initialize the basic's of the class, `setUpSomething` is used to set up stuff after initialization using values passed in but before the object get's used. Clear separation between creation, setup and use.

Comment: Thematrix - I like the static `class << self` layout. Thanks for the note on redudancy mudasobwa.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case you likely need a class instance variable:

```
class MyUtil
  @apiClient = Vendor::API::Client.new("mykey")

  def self.setUpSomething(param1, param2, param3=nil)
    @apiClient.call("foo", param2)
    # some logic and more util.apiClient.calls() re-use client.
  end
end
```

If you want a lazy instantiation, use an accessor:

```
class MyUtil
  class << self
    def api_client
      @apiClient ||= Vendor::API::Client.new("mykey")
    end

    def setUpSomething(param1, param2, param3=nil)
      apiClient.call("foo", param2)
      # some logic and more util.apiClient.calls() re-use client.
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The APIClient setup thing was a bit oversimplified for example. I have a handful of class methods including 2 api clients and others. It was more about how to call the object methods statically - the `class << self` static subclass is a great suggestion - i have another class that has about 10 methods all defined as `def self.x` which is painful.  `util = new` is clean to read in the static method (or via yield / code block)

Comment: The proper way would be to declare these 10 methods in a separate module and `MyUtil.extend ThisModule` afterwards, not `class << self`.

Comment: It's purely a static class, there are no object methods. How would a static-only class be defined? `class X << self` ?

Comment: There is no “static-only” class in Ruby, since at every moment anybody could reopen the class and make it non-static. The common pattern would be to declare a `module` having all functions declared as `module_function`.

Answer (score 1):

Brett, what do you think about this:

```
class MyUtil
  API_KEY = 'SECRET'

  def do_something(data)
    api_client.foo(data)
  end

  def do_something_else(data)
    api_client.foo(data)
    api_client.bar(data)
  end

  private

  def api_client
    @api_client ||= Vendor::API::Client.new(API_KEY)
  end
end
```

Usage

```
s = MyUtil.new
s.do_something('Example') # First call
s.do_something_else('Example 2')
```

Comment: I was looking for `calling object methods from a static method` as an alternative to having to instantiate the class during usage.